# Best way for multi-threaded inserts and updates on a mysql table with String primary key?

Tags: mysql, multithreading, insert, multiprocessing, deadlock

It seems like a simple question, but I am not able to figure out the best possible solution to this problem. I have a multithreaded as well as multiprocessing framework with reasonable concurrency(6-7 threads over 3 machines). Each process either inserts into or updates the same table which has a string field as the primary key. What will be the best possible way to ensure a thread-safe execution and avoid deadlocks ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks,
Amit

Comment: Set the isolation level on the database connection appropriately: SERIALIZABLE is the most stringent.

Answer (score 0):

You could append the queries into a Redis set from multiple threads. Then in another single thread to manage these queries into two (one insert and one update) and do the db operation from that thread. Then the deadlock can be avoided.